# php curl class, Sending Curl request with Content Type json

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to send a json post request to a url. I am using `php curl class`. But my request header is always showing content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if even I have set up content type. Here is my code

```
 $curl1 = new Curl();

$curl1->setOpt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$curl1->setOpt(CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
$curl1->setOpt(CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
$curl1->setOpt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$curl1->setOpt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "content-type:application/json"

));
$curl1->setBasicAuthentication('username', 'password');

$curl1->post('https://example.com/url');
```

I am getting `500 error` from api. I have contacted them, they said your content type isn't right. I have print out my content type that looks like

```
CaseInsensitiveArray Object
(
[container:Curl\CaseInsensitiveArray:private] => Array
    (
        [Request-Line] => POST /url HTTP/1.1
        [Authorization] => Basic Yccx4MzA1ZTU0MDkwNDA3OGI1OWI4YjUyNjI4MjJjNTM6MTddfhf7755Y1ZDQ0NDVmY2I2NTEzZjllNTU3MzI4MTM=
        [User-Agent] => PHP-Curl-Class/3.4.5 (+https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) PHP/5.5.24 curl/7.36.0
        [Host] => ssapi.shipstation.com
        [Accept] => */*
        [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    )

)
```

Please check the content type in request headers and in my code. They are different. I am setting `Content-Type: applicaiton/json` then why in request it is showing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

And here is the json that I am sending

```
 {"orderNumber":"BENORDER","orderDate":"2015-05-31T03:38:36-0700","orderStatus":"awaiting_shipment","billTo":{"name":"Stack Yu","company":null,"street1":" Stockton AVenue","city":"Plainfield","state":"IL","postalCode":"44444"},"shipTo":{"name":"Stack Yu","company":null,"street1":" Stockton AVenue","city":"Plainfield","state":"IL","postalCode":"44444"},"items":[{"sku":"S102","name":"My Prodcut","quantity":"1"}]}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-curl-class has a separate method for setting a header, check [the documentation](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/docs/source/index.md). So, you have to use:

```
$curl1->setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and the `Content-Type` header will be set.